# "ORA-00911: invalid character" coming when calling oracle procedure from java

Tags: java, stored-procedures, plsql, ora-00911

I have a procedure which is working fine when i run on sql developer.

```
    create or replace
    PROCEDURE test(Order in varchar,Id in number ,status out varchar) As
    logic
    dbms_output.put_line(status);
    end;
```

However when i am calling this procedure from java it showing error ORA-00911: invalid character.My java code is

```
    String proc3StoredProcedure=null;
    try {
        proc3StoredProcedure = "{ test(?,?,?) }";

            } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         System.out.println("exception");

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(proc3StoredProcedure);
    cs.setEscapeProcessing(false);


    cs.setString(1,"17");
    cs.setInt(2,37);

    cs.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    cs.execute();

    String param4 = cs.getString(2);




    System.out.println("param4=" + param4);


    conn.close();
}
```

What I am doing wrong in java code.I have tried many things but its not wroking.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the string assigned to `proc3StoredProcedure` to `{ call test(?,?,?) }`.

[Docs for JDBC SQL escape syntax here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13157_01/wlevs/docs30/jdbc_drivers/sqlescape.html). (The syntax for procedure calls is at the very bottom of the linked page).

Comment: thanks Bob.Apart from the mistake you pointed out,I needed to set cs.setEscapeProcessing(true) instead of false or delete that statement.I inserted that statement coz it was giving SQL token error as I haven't included 'call' word in '{ call test(?,?,?) }'.